# How can I add a proxy server to the jira plugin in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jira

I my jenkins job, I need to check the blocked issues in jira, if there is any issued in blocked level. than the job will stop.

the jenkins server is in the inner network of our custom company. The Jira server is in our office and published to the internet.

so the jenkins server need to using a proxy server to access the lira server.

but I can't find the way to config the proxy server.(In the 'Manager Plugins' page of jenkins there has been set a proxy, but it seems not work for lira plugin)

Comment: In the 'Manager Plugins' page of jenkins there has been set a proxy, but it seems not work for lira plugin

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?  I can't get this to work either.  I also tried adding http.proxyHost and http.proxyPort to the Jenkins JVM and that didn't help either.

Comment: no i just ignore the feature of "check blocked issue(s) in jira" in my CI step.